# Coding issues with while loop

Tags: if-statement, while-loop

I have a relatively simple issue using while loop. I am not sure what I am missing. I have an equation that computes `r` and I want to check whether or not it lies in some range. The following is what I have (I am just writing the main part):

```
  r = r + 0.2*dt*randn;
  r_temp = r;
  while r_temp<1.28 && r_temp>1.45
      r = r + 0.2*dt*randn;
      r_temp = r;
      if r_temp>1.28 && r_temp<1.45
          break
      end
  end
```

Basically, I need the above while loop to continue until `r` is inside `1.28<r<1.45`. Can someone please advise as to what I may be missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are searching for "Or"-statement, which is `||` to be on the right way.
Edit: Too slow :(

Answer (score 0):

`while r_temp<1.28 && r_temp>1.45` continues while `r_temp` is both less than 1.28 *and* greater than 1.45. That can't happen. You want `||`, not `&&`.

Comment: @user2468702: Did you change both the `while` and the `if`? You should only change the `while`.